# Same size on figure and colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, astropy

I simple plot a fits file and I drawn a colorbar on the right. I'm not be able to regulate the sizes of the image and the colorbar, I want them on the same size.
Furthermore I would like to know how the change the labels of the color bar, like a `ax0.set_xticks()` and `ax0.set_xticklabels()` which I normally use on simple plots.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from astropy.io import fits
import copy
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm, Normalize
from regions import read_ds9

fits_file = "fb.fits"
hdul = fits.open(fits_file)
image_data = hdul[0].data
wcs = WCS(hdul[0].header)
hdul.close()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax0=fig.add_subplot(111, projection=wcs)

norm = LogNorm(10,1)
my_cmap = copy.copy(matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Blues_r'))
my_cmap.set_bad((0,0,0))
im = ax0.imshow(image_data, cmap=my_cmap, norm=norm)
bar = fig.colorbar(im)


reg_file = "astropy.reg"
regs = read_ds9(reg_file, errors='warn')
for i, reg in enumerate(regs):
    reg.plot(ax=ax0)

ax0.set_title('')
ax0.set_xlabel('RA')
ax0.set_ylabel('DEC')
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0.08, 0.08, 0.94, 0.9])

plt.show()
```

And the final image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`shrink`](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes) as argument for your colorbar.
From [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html#matplotlib.colorbar.make_axes):

> *shrink*  fraction by which to multiply the size of the colorbar

Have a look at the link, other options are possible, like setting a padding or the the aspect-ratio.

Something like this might work for you:

```
bar = fig.colorbar(im, shrink=0.8)
```

---

You can `set_yticklabels` on the axes object your colorbar lives in (you get it with `bar.ax`). If you want to specify the ticklabels yourself, don't forget the first specify the tick locations.

So something like:

```
# `myticklocs` are the locations and `mylabels` are your labels
bar = fig.colormap(im, ticks=myticklocs)
bar.ax.set_yticklabels(mylabels, weight='bold', size=9)
```

Have a look at the minimal [official labelling demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html).

Comment: You misspelled shrink

Comment: `bar.ax.set_yticklabels()` doesn't work... it overplots the new labels...

Comment: @Bazingaa thanks! fixed it. To bad this does not support `flake8` :)

Comment: I cannot remove the labels... I tried with `bar.ax.set_yticklabels([])` and `bar.ax.set_yticklabels([])` without success.